# 3.5" SATA Seagate Barracuda not mounting via USB adapter

Tags: hard-drive, imac, usb, mount, sata

I have a late 2009 27" iMac which I upgraded with a OWC SSD kit. Fantastic results, I highly recommend it, feels like a new machine. But I was facing problems restoring from a Time Machine back-up and started from scratch.

I have now the original Seagate in the wild, which I am trying to connect via a powered (12V) SATA 2/USB 3.0 adapter.

[image]

[image]

The drive does not show in Finder or Disk Utility. The Seagate is powered since it ticks when plugged. But just ticks, it does not seem to spin or make the noises I was used to when it was in the iMac.

My objectives are:

1. See if I can get a hold of 500 GB+ of movies in there
2. Delete the whole thing before recycling it

Additional info: the Barracuda is *as is*, like it was in the iMac, meaning with a bootable High Sierra. I cannot see it from the booting menu (Option key at start up) though. It was failing since it started to tick, but it was still working when I turned off the iMac to install the SSD.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: A clicking drive is never a good sign. It strongly hints at a physical failure.

Comment: You are right, hence I swapped it with an SSD. But thing is, it was still working the minute before I started opening the iMac.